# PHPUnit error for trying to install

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, pecl

Does anyone know why when I try to install PHPUnit onto my mac osx 10.8.2 I get this error?

```
Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com
Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.2
phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "channel://pear.symfony.com/Yaml" (version >= 2.1.0, version <= 2.1.99)
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1.0, version <= 1.1.99)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

I have installed pear properly as below:

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.2
PHP Version: 5.3.6
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Darwin Macintosh-2.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Also looked at making symfony available with this and it says its all okay:

```
Macintosh-2:~ mdunbavan$ pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is already initialized
Macintosh-2:~ mdunbavan$
```

Has anyone got any idea?

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please compare the error:

```
Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com
```

... with your fix:

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

URLs do not match.

Comment: after doing pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com I got the same saying it was already initialised?

Comment: Yeah, doing it twice won't change the result. Have you read my answer?

Comment: Discovering channel pear.symfony.com over http:// failed with message: channel-add: Cannot open "http://pear.symfony.com/channel.xml" (could not open /tmp/pear/install/channel.xml for writing)
Trying to discover channel pear.symfony.com over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "pear.symfony.com" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https://pear.symfony.com/channel.xml" (Connection to `pear.symfony.com:443' failed: Connection refused))

Comment: And can you write to `/tmp/pear/install/channel.xml`?

Comment: no I get permission denied, shall I make it writable with chmod?

Comment: I know nothing about Macs, but it's possible that you need to `sudo` or something in order to install programs.

Comment: ah ha that worked, your genius installed phpunit but now I get this weird error when I do a php unit test sh: phpunit: command not found
You have mail in /var/mail/mdunbavan

Comment: 1) You don't have a `phpunit` command in your current user's PATH 2) You have received one or more e-mail messages in your local inbox.

Comment: whats the best way to remedy the first problem?

Comment: Run `pear config-show`, find out where `bin_dir` is, check if you have `phpunit` there...

Comment: hmm not I see no phpunit in bin_dir, it should be in there right?

Comment: It is my Windows box, but I installed PHPUnit from the official channel, not sure if Symphony's release is different.

Comment: I wonder why it throws that error then? seems strange as I followed all the right paths with installing it right?

Comment: What's the exact command you used to install PHPUnit? I see no trace of it at [http://pear.symfony.com/](http://pear.symfony.com/) :-?